# Norm of operator on $\ell_2$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am having trouble computing the norm of the following operator:
$$T:\ell_2 \to \ell_2$$ given by $$T(x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots) = \left(x_1, \frac{x_2}{2}, \frac{x_3}{3},\dots\right).$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to find

$$
\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Tx\|_2.
$$

We have, for every $x \in \ell_2$ with $\|x\|_2=1$,
$$
\|Tx\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{x_i}{i}\right)^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i^2 = \|x\|_2^2=1.
$$
so $\|T\| \leq 1$.

By considering $x=(1, 0 \dots, 0, \dots)$ we see that $\|x\|=1$ and $Tx=x$, so $\|Tx\|_2=1$, hence $\|T\| \geq 1$, so we can conclude $\|T\|=1$.